# Sharing one service between two activities without destroying it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I'm working on an application to communicate with a raspberry pi. The app communicates with the server via a socket connection.

I'm currently able to building up the communication and holding it in a service. But my goal is to change from activity A to activity B. The problem is, that my application destroys the service when im switching the activities. Is there a way to avoid this?

Activity A starts the service and when im starting Activity B i bind it to the activity to call the methods in the service class. But it isn't the same instance.

How could i solve this?

**Code**

**ConnectActivity**

```
package com.example.domen.twitchdronev3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int port = 3000;
    private String ip = "localhost";
    private Intent serviceIntent, activityIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starte App...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        activityIntent = new Intent(this, ControllActivity.class);
        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ClientService.class);

        serviceIntent.putExtra("ip", ip);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("port", port);

        Button btnActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeActivity);
        btnActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(serviceIntent);
                activityIntent.putExtra("Intent", (Parcelable) serviceIntent);
                startActivity(activityIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    // destroys the Activity
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Destroy (ConnectActivity)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Activity stopping
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

**ControllActivity**

```
package com.example.domen.twitchdronev3;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ControllActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "ControllActivity";

    private ClientService clientservice;
    private Intent serviceIntent;
    private boolean isBound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_controll);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        serviceIntent = extras.getParcelable("Intent");

        Button btnDisconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisconnect);
        btnDisconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                doBindToService();
            }
        });
    }

    // destroys the Activity
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Destroy (ControllActivity)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        doUnbindToService();
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }

    // Functions to BIND and UNBIND the SERVICE
    // bind to Service
    public void doBindToService(){
        if(!isBound) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "(doBindToService) Binding...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            isBound = bindService(serviceIntent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }

    // Unbind to Service
    public void doUnbindToService(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "(doUnbindToService) Unbinding...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        unbindService(myConnection);
        isBound = false;
    }

    private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection(){
        public static final String TAG = "ConnectActivity";

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service){
            Log.i(TAG, "BOUND SERVICE CONNECTED");
            clientservice = ((ClientService.ClientBinder) service).getService();
            isBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name){
            Log.i(TAG, "BOUND SERVICE DISCONNECTED");
            clientservice = null;
            isBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

**ClientService**

```
package com.example.domen.twitchdronev3;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by ViTrex on 12.02.2018.
 */

public class ClientService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "ClientService";
    private final IBinder mBinder = new ClientBinder();

    private PrintWriter out;
    private Socket socket;

    private String ip = "";
    private int port = 0;

    private Thread backgroundThread;

    // the class used for the client binder
    public class ClientBinder extends Binder {
        ClientService getService() {
            // returns the instance of ClientService
            // so the client can access the public methods
            return ClientService.this;
        }
    }

    //SETTER
    public void setIP(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    //GETTER
    public String getIP() {
        return this.ip;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return this.port;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate...");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(intent != null){
            setIP(intent.getStringExtra("ip"));
            setPort(intent.getIntExtra("port", 3000));
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind called...");
        Toast.makeText(this, getIP() + " " + getPort(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                buildConnection();
            }
        });
        backgroundThread.start();
        return mBinder;
    }

    private void buildConnection() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Try to build up a connection ...");
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                this.socket = new Socket(getIP(), getPort());
                this.out = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.i(TAG, ioe.getMessage());
                this.socket = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "Close Service");
        Thread dummy = backgroundThread;
        backgroundThread = null;
        if (dummy != null)
            dummy.interrupt();

        if (this.socket != null) {
            try {
                this.out.close();
                this.socket.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "Close Socket");
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ERROR: Close Socket");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant code, please?

Comment: Ok, i edited the code

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Activity A starts the service and when I'm starting Activity B I bind
>   it to the activity to call the methods in the service class. But it
>   isn't the same instance.

- How do you know it is ***not*** the same instance (*presumably* you mean *of* the `service` instance)?
- I think your code is o.k. to run  on older devices (*It runs o.k. on my device*. `pre-API26`, I think permissions changed after then so *maybe* more code needed. See *NOTE* at the end of this answer).
- Don't you want START_STICKY ?

I would add this code (read the `Intent data` that was setup by `Activity A`)  to your `ClientService.java`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{

    String a_ip   = intent.getStringExtra("ip");
    int    a_port = intent.getIntExtra("port",-1);  
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand called...with " + "ip:" + a_ip + "and port:"+ a_port);   
    setIP(a_ip);
    setPort(a_port);        

    return START_NOT_STICKY;//don't you want START_STICKY ?
    }
```

> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes
>   restrictions on using or creating background services unless the app
>   itself is in the foreground. If an app needs to create a foreground
>   service, the app should call StartForegroundService(). That method
>   creates a background service, but the method signals to the system
>   that the service will promote itself to the foreground. Once the
>   service has been created, the service must call its startForeground()
>   method within five seconds. From [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Activity A has created an instance and in Activity B i created another instance. Thank you :) Your answer helped me. I read the guide carefully. I'm not using the startForeground() method. Currently i'm starting a service with startService(intent) in activity A and share the intent with activity B. When activity B has started, i'm calling the bindService(intent) method and create a toast. It showed me the same values that i have shared when i called startService(intent). But i'll try it with the startForeground() method.

Comment: Your comment above is confusing,  `"It showed me the same values that i have shared"`. In the code you have given us, no such Toast exists, and it could not work without the code I gave you, because you are not **reading** the intent values and "saving them in  variables " in your service code.

Comment: Excuse me, i forgot to edit the post and did not express myself very well. I edited my post.